# form submit leading to redirect after auth changes

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

After the recent `auth` changes, one application stopped submitting forms properly, and I can't figure out why. Here's my situation:

I have multiple apps that all point to the same codebase. Each app comes in with a separate identifier so i know which app to display. All of my apps are working perfectly except one, which happens to be an older app (I created it in the summer, the rest were created within the past couple weeks, post-migrations).

I am using the `php sdk (3.1.1)` and all of my forms have actions of `action="mysite.com/controller/function"` instead of `"apps.facebook.com/appname/controller/function"`. As of yesterday (December 15), when my one app submits the form, the receiving page is not finding any `facebook` connection and thus is breaking.

Once again, for most of my apps the receiving function is able to connect via `$this->facebook->getUser()`. It's only the one app where that returns null.

How is this possible? All of my apps use the same codebase, and I've programmatically made sure their migrations all look like this, the setting of the apps that work:

```
 migrations=
    {
     "disable_auth_methods":true,"secure_stream_urls":false,"december_rollup":true,"apprequest_
    counts":true,"page_tab_iframe":true,"read_notifications_permission":false,"recent_activity"
    :true,"app_profile_page_deprecation":false,"gdp_v2":false,"page_hours_format":false,"graph_
    batch_api_exception_format":false
}
```

Is there a setting wrong with my app? How else is it possible that the same codebase can serve two apps and have them act differently? I feel like I've changed every app setting I could find to no avail.

By the way: I know it's possible to have the action be `apps.facebook.com/nameofapp` but it doesn't solve the problem as to why this worked and then doesn't now. I'd like to root out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I completely missed a setting, and in hindsight it's very simple. My canvas url for the non-working app was:

```
http://www.mysite.com
```

and my form action was:

```
http://mysite.com
```

all the other apps had a canvas url without the `www.` and they worked fine. apparently when it went from `www.` to `mysite.com`, it would lose its facebook connection and need to redirect to the permissions page.

I hope this helps someone else out.